# How to know in php when sql fetched rows share the same ID and when a new set of IDs begins

Tags: php

Hi all so I have a stored procedure where I return a list of all orders placed within a given week. However I currently show all orders grouped by the SaleID of each order. In other words when I run the stored procedure I get all the orders but all purchases grouped together.
Like

```
    SaleID  Name   Item         Qty
    5020021 John   Blue Cheese  1
    5020021 John   Bread        1
    5020256 Carol  Milk         1
    5020256 Carol  Box of eggs  1
    5020256 Carol  Oat Milk     1
```

In php I am displaying all these orders as a list format but I would like to know when a new orders begins and ends. Not sure if this is doable I have looked online but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: It would probably be better to use relations in your database, eg multiple tables that point to each other, instead of duplicating the data in multiple rows.

Comment: But is what I am saying doable? I unfortunately don't write the stored procedures or handle much of the database.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible, assuming there is a `date` column (you did not put one in the example)

Comment: no there isn't a date column but isn't the saleID all I would need to distinguish the difference between rows?

Comment: Show us your select query from PHP file.

Comment: @Boxer19 You said in the question that you would like to get all orders placed in a week, but if you only want unique SaleIDs, you do not need a date column.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple `if()` check when you save the last `SaleId` in a variable. This way you can compare the current `SaleId` with the previous one. The code might look like this:

```
$lastSaleId = null;
while ($row = /* ... */) {
    if ($lastSaleId != $row['SaleId']) {
        // new sale
        echo "Sale ".$row['SaleId']." by ".$row['Name']."<br />";
    }
    echo "* ".$row['Qty']."x ".$row['Item']"<br />";
    $lastSaleId = $row['SaleId'];
}
```

Comment: ah I see. Okay so if I wasn't echoing the results right then and there and instead I was trying to send it back as JSON, would I be able to do this by using a nested array to return the information like the name and saleID one time and then return the items for each purchase?

Comment: I tried this and It doesn't work, it will  display all the items and Qty for all the orders instead of printing the item for each order. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Boxer19 If you want to build a JSON object and send the data back you can do that. Building an array like `{name, saleId, [item=>qty]}` (pseudo code) will work. But problems with that will most likely be a different question than you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` for this.

```sql
SELECT SaleID FROM table GROUP BY SaleID ORDER BY SaleID DESC
```